# Column name and row value as KEY VALUE PAIR type in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Table:

```
Id Name Age Country
1  AAAA 12  AU
2  BBBB 13  CC
```

How to get the result as TAB of KEYVALUE PAIR the column names and corresponding values? For example for id 1, the result should be like

```
[
  {Name:AAAA},
  {Age: 12},
  {Country: AU}
]
```

Comment: *the result should be like*??

Comment: So you want the data returned as JSON? What version of Oracle database are you running?

Comment: If you want to generate JSON from the database, [Oracle 12.2 can do this natively](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adjsn/generation.html). Prior to that you may need DBMS_SQL.

Comment: No not as json. I want the result as native oracle types. 
I have a type TYPE KEYVALUEPAIR<VARCHAR, VARCHAR>.
The result should be VARRAY<KEYVALUEPAIR>

Comment: Are you looking for json result?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `UNPVIVOT` and `LISTAGG`.

```
SELECT ID,   
    '['|| 
        LISTAGG ('{' || col || ':' || VALUE || '}', ',')
        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ROWNUM)
    || ']'  key_value_pair
FROM (SELECT id,Name, TO_CHAR (age) age, Country FROM yourtable) 
UNPIVOT (VALUE FOR col IN (Name, Age, Country)) 
GROUP BY id;
```

**Output**

```
| ID |                      KEY_VALUE_PAIR |
|----|-------------------------------------|
|  1 | [{NAME:AAAA},{AGE:12},{COUNTRY:AU}] |
|  2 | [{NAME:BBBB},{AGE:13},{COUNTRY:CC}] |
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7e191/20)

You said you have a `TYPE KEYVALUEPAIR<VARCHAR,VARCHAR>`. Are you probably wanting to use something like this?

```
DECLARE
TYPE KEYVALUEPAIR
IS
  RECORD
  (
    KEY_   VARCHAR2(12),
    VALUE_ VARCHAR2(12) );
TYPE RECTYPE IS VARRAY(10) OF KEYVALUEPAIR;
RECID1 RECTYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT col,
    VALUE BULK COLLECT
  INTO RECID1
  FROM
    (SELECT id, Name, TO_CHAR (age) age, Country FROM yourtable WHERE ID = 1
    ) UNPIVOT (VALUE FOR col IN (Name, Age, Country)) ;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your main request is to use a VARARY collection or to have the data in the format you mentioned.

If you need to use a VARRAY collection, here is an example:

```
declare
    type t_1 is varray(10) of test_1%ROWTYPE;
    v_1 t_1:=t_1();
    j number;
begin
    v_1.extend(2);
    j := 1;
    for i in (select * from test_1)
    loop
        v_1(j).id       := i.id;
        v_1(j).name     := i.name;
        v_1(j).age      := i.age;
        v_1(j).country  := i.country;
        j := j + 1;
    end loop;

    for j in v_1.first .. v_1.last
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line ('v_1(' || j || ').id = ' || v_1(j).id);
        dbms_output.put_line ('v_1(' || j || ').name = ' || v_1(j).name);
        dbms_output.put_line ('v_1(' || j || ').age = ' || v_1(j).age);
        dbms_output.put_line ('v_1(' || j || ').country = ' || v_1(j).country);
        dbms_output.put_line ('---------------------------------');        
    end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    select id, 
       json_array( json_object('name' value name)
                 , json_object('age' value age)
                 , json_object('country' value country)) key_values
  from 
  ( select 1 id, 'AAAA' name, 12 age, 'AU' country from dual 
     union all
    select 2 id, 'BBBB' name, 13 age, 'CC' country from dual ) a
```